# On the proof that if $\operatorname{dim} X=\infty$, then the identity operator $I\colon X\to X$ is not compact.

Tags: functional-analysis

Currently I'm self studying functional analysis, namely compact operators. In the text, the author gives the following lemma:

> **Lemma 1**: Let $E_1$ be a closed subspace of $E$ such that $E\neq E_1\hookrightarrow E\hookrightarrow X$. Then there exists $y_0\in E$ with $||y_0||_X=1$ and such that the distance of $y_0$ to $E_1$ satisfies $\operatorname{dist}(y_0,E_1)\geq1/2$.

I completely understand **Lemma 1**. The author then gives the following corollary:

> **Corollary A**: If $\operatorname{dim} X=\infty$, then the identity operator $I\colon X\to X$ is not compact.

I understand the statement of **Corollary A**. The author then provides the following proof:

*Proof*. It is enough to see that the unit ball $B_X:=\left\{x\in X: ||x||_X\leq1\right\}$ is not a compact set. Consider any family of subspaces $E_1\hookrightarrow E_2\hookrightarrow\cdots\hookrightarrow E_n\hookrightarrow \cdots$ where $\operatorname{dim}E_n=n$. They are closed subspaces (since they are of finite dimension) and by **Lemma 1**, there exists a sequence $y_i\in E_i$ with $||y_i||_X=1$ such that $\operatorname{dist}(y_i,E_{i-1})\geq1/2$. Then for any $i\neq j$, $||y_i-y_j||_X\geq1/2$. Obviously, $\{y_i\}$ is not a Cauchy sequence and there is no Cauchy subsequence of it.

This is where some questions arise for me.

**Question 1**: Why did the author introduce the unit ball $B_X$ in the proof? It seems to me that the author constructed a bounded sequence $\{y_i\}$ ($||y_i||_X=1$) in the domain $X$ for which the image $\{Iy_i\}=\{y_i\}$ under the operator $I$ has no Cauchy subsequence. This alone shows that the operator $I$ is not compact.

**Question 2**: Where was the hypothesis that $\operatorname{dim}X=\infty$ used in the proof? I assume it was used to construct an *infinite* sequence $\{y_i\}$ in $X$, but do we really need an infinite sequence here? That is, couldn't we just have used a finite sequence $\{y_i\}_1^n$?

Comment: Existence of $E_i$'s uses infinite dimensionality of $X$.

Comment: Your last question is strange.  Can you elaborate on how you think you could use a finite sequence?  We essentially need an infinite subset with no limit point, so just using a finite sequence is insufficient (otherwise we'd be able to show the nonexistence of compact sets?).

Comment: @BrianMoehring: So, to me it seems the statement: "Then for any $i\neq j$, $||y_i-y_j||_X\geq1/2$. Obviously, $\{y_i\}$ is not a Cauchy sequence and there is no Cauchy subsequence of it", would still hold true even if the sequence was finite. Thus $\{y_i\}$ has no Cauchy subsequence, so $I$ cannot be compact. I must be wrong somewhere here since then no use of $X$ being infinite dimensional is used...but I'm just not sure where!

Comment: You need to start with an honest [infinite] sequence to investigate [sequential] compactness.  Starting with a finite sequence is somewhat meaningless.

Comment: This may clarify: Take  $y_1\in X$ with $\|y_1\|=1$. Let $E_1=Span(\{y_1\}).$  Recursively, if $E_n$ is $n$-dimensional then $E_n\ne X$ because $X$ is infinite-dimensional, so take $y_{n+1}\in X$ \ $E_n$ with $\|y_{n+1}\|=1$ and $dist(y_{n+1},E_n)\ge 1/2.$ And let $E_{n+1}=Span(E_n\cup \{y_{n+1}\}).$  Recursive constructions like this are often incorrectly called "inductive".

Comment: A subsequence of a finite sequence is obviously also finite. No finite sequence is Cauchy, as there is a lower limit to the distances between any two elements (just choose the smallest distance from that finite list). Any set with at least two elements has finite sequences in it. Thus by your argument, the only compact sets would be $\emptyset$ and singleton sets. This is why the concepts of Cauchy sequences and sequential compactness only make sense for infinite sequences.